# Access external Network from a computer in the network

Tags: networking, router, iptables, ipv6, forwarding

My network architecture is like this:

[image: This picture]

Now I want to be able ping **PC1** and **PC2** from **Debian** computer according to the architecture above.

Which configuration in the `routing table`, `Iptables` or other software I should use to enable **Debian** computer ping the network behind **Router3**?

Comment: Do you understand why they cannot communicate now?

Comment: @MichaelHampton: I think because the computer between them (**Ubuntu**) doesn't know to forward packet arrived at **eth0** adapter to **tun0** interface.

Comment: So obviously you have to configure the **Ubuntu** computer and **Router 3** correctly... You may also have to tunnel IPv4 (e.g. over GRE) if the bottom right part in your picture is IPv6 only.

Comment: @dirkt So my question is what is the correct config?

Comment: You need to enable forwarding and set proper routes (google). You'll also have to tell us if you want to work over IPv4 or IPv6, if you can assign IPv4 addresses to the right part, or if you can assign global IPv6 addresses to the left part (`fe80` is link only, you can't route these). If you can do neither, you have to decide how to set up a tunnel, or if you want to use some kind of IPv6 to IPv4 translation. So the answer is "it depends". Also, it can get a bit difficult, depending on what you can do or can't do.

Comment: @dirkt I can't assign IPv4 to the bottom right network. It's IPv6 Only. I cant work with IPv4 only in **Debian** and **Ubuntu** computers. Your opinion is using global IPv6 in the right bottom network, yes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Partial answer:

If you can, the simplest way is to assign routable IPv6 addresses both to the Debian and the Ubuntu computer. If you can't get a proper prefix from somewhere, use a [unique local address](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv6_address#Special_addresses) (they start with `fc00::...`) prefix.

You can list addresses with `ip addr show`, and add addresses manually with `ip addr add ...`. In the same way, you can list routes with `ip route show` and add routes with `ip route add ...`. Use `ip -6 ...` to get only IPv6 information. Read the man pages for details.

Make all machines, in particular both **Ubuntu** and **Router 3**, but also **Debian** and **PC1** and **PC2** have correct routes with correct next hops for all hosts you want to reach. A correct default gateway may be sufficient (esp. on Debian/PC1/PC2), if you have one.

You can verify with `ip route get aaaa::212:7403:3:303` etc. that the route works. Router 3 should have forwarding already enabled, enable it with `sysctl -w net.ipv6.conf.all.forwarding=1` on **Ubuntu** if necessary.

Use `ping6` to test, run `tcpdump -ni eth0` etc. on all interesting hosts/interfaces to verify that the packets go where they should go.

Once everything works, you can make the configuration permanent. That depends a bit on how you've setup machines (systemd? network manager? Something else?).

Comment: Please try not to encourage people to literally use `fc00::` instead of a proper ULA prefix.

Comment: @MichaelHampton: Of course I am not encouraging them literally to use `fc00::`. Feel free to add a comment and describe how they should choose a proper prefix.

Comment: The point is that the way the sentence is currently constructed, it may easily be misinterpreted that way. This is something that you should edit. For others to do so might change the meaning of the post, which editors should avoid doing.

Comment: @MichaelHampton: I'm not a native speaker of English. I'll gladly accept any edit which will avoid misinterpretation. Feel free to propose one. If you don't want to edit, do it in a comment.

Comment: I don't think it's necessary to have the literal string `fc00::` present at all. It's only confusing to people who don't understand ULAs fully. Merely stating «unique local address» is enough.

Comment: @MichaelHampton: People who have never heard about ULAs will be even more confused if they don't have a way to identify them. I made an edit, and left the `fc00::`. Feel free to propose a better edit.